# AudioSession.h iOS SDK 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

I try to code on iOS SDK 5.0 (can't update my xcode). And here is some problem: no AudioSession.h in AudioToolbox/AudioUnit frameworks. Is it in SDK 6? 
I know that AudioSession is deprecated in SDK 7. But it must be in 5, isn't it? What's wrong?..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try: `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioSession.h>`, not tested with iOS5 but with iOS6.

Comment: error: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'AudioToolbox/AudioSession.h' file not found, here is no file in the directory with sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that AudioSession is included in AudioService.h.